# Naivedyam / offering of food

Tags: worship

Namaste,

When making food for naivedyam, is it ok to save half of it, especially the stuffing (poornam) and use it next time to make fresh food (example: poli, kozhukkattai, etc) and offer it to god?

That is, if the stuffing gets to be too much, you can save it and reuse it to make fresh food for offering to god again in future?